# Spring Integration Java DSL Filter w/ Routing

Tags: java, spring-integration

Spring Integration 5.x here (Java DSL). I am interested in implementing a filter as part of my `IntegrationFlow` that has the following logic:

- if the inbound message has a header of "fruit", then I want it routed to the "fruit-channel" (regardless of the fruit header's value)
- otherwise I want the message sent to a discard channel/dead letter queue

My best attempt at the filter itself:

```
public class FruitFilter {

    @Filter
    public boolean fruitsOnly(Message<?> message) {
        return message.getHeaders().containsKey("fruit");
    }

}
```

And my best attempt at using this filter in a flow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fruitFlow() {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(ingressChannel())

        .filter(fruitFilter)

        // TODO #1: how to route messages (containing the fruit header) on to the "fruit-channel"?
        // TODO #2: how to process messages that were filtered and sent to the discard/DLQ channel?
        .get();

}
```

I think the Java code and use of Spring Integration's API is OK above, but I'm not understanding where/how I place the actual filter-based *routing*. Can anyone spot where I'm going awry here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@Filter` impl is OK, although it could be just made as an in-line lambda. The `fruit-channel` should be just an output of this `filter()` endpoint. The `error-channel` must be configured as a `discardChannel` option of that `filter()`. So, the solution for your task might look like this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fruitFlow() {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(ingressChannel())
            .filter(fruitFilter, "fruitsOnly", e -> e.discardChannel("error-channel"))
            .channel("fruit-channel")
            .get();

}
```

That's if you stick with your `FruitFilter` bean. However this one would let you to avoid that one as well:

```
 .filter(Message.class, message -> message.getHeaders().containsKey("fruit"), e -> e.discardChannel("error-channel"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Artem (+1) -- is the second string argument `"fruitsOnly"` necessary even if I am using the `@Filter` annotation on the filter method? And if so, what is the point of the `@Filter` annotation?

Comment: There is no way to have a `filter(Object, Consumer)` signature to avoid Java ambiguity. That's why only a signature requesting method name to call is there for us. You can remove that annotation, or you can move all the `input`, `output` and `discard` channel configurations to that annotation and remove this `IntegrationFlow` at all: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations